# Can't get MySQL and Tomcat to communicate

Tags: java, jdbc, tomcat7

I have searched for answers in a few sites and have followed all the directions, but I can't get a connection to MySql from my web app running in Tomcat 7. Here is my contect.xml entry (context.xml located in META-INF folder):

```
<Resource name="jdbc/superpool"
  global="jdbc/superpool"
  auth="Container"
  type="javax.sql.DataSource"
  driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/superpool"
  username="devuser"
  password="devuser"

  maxActive="100"
  maxIdle="20"
  minIdle="5"
  maxWait="10000"/>
```

And here is my web.xml entry (located in WEB-INF folder)

```
  <resource-ref>
     <description>SuperPool MySQL Datasource </description>
     <res-ref-name>jdbc/superpool</res-ref-name>
     <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
     <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
 </resource-ref>
```

And here is my java code:

```
Connection c = null;
try {
    InitialContext initCtx = new InitialContext();
    Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");

    DataSource ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/superpool");
    //c = ds.getConnection("devuser", "devuser");
    c = ds.getConnection();
} catch (NamingException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The exception I get is:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'superpool'

I suspect it's because it doesn't know where the database is located but I'm not sure where to put the DB file(s). I tried Tomcat ROOT directory and WEB-INF, but still can't connect. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you try to connect manually from command line using mysql command?  That will make sure that the DB is up and running locally on port 3306.

Comment: After you do as @mjuarez suggested, you may want to try with a simple main to make sure you got the correct connection data:  **Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/superpool","devuser","devuser");**